# jQuery 同classのinputタグから入力済みのものだけへの処理をループを使わずに書く方法

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">　　
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
```

上記のようなHTMLにて、
入力されているinputタグに処理をしたいのですが、

```
$('.input').each(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $(this).hogehoge;
  }
});
```

↑のようにループ等使わずに、

```
$('xxxxxx').hogehoge;
```

と、1行で書く事はできないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: フォームとは何を指しますか？htmlにはformタグというものがありますが、inputタグのことに読めます。用語を正しく使って下さい。

Comment: 失礼しました。これでどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やりたい事によっては、input要素を`required="required`にしておき、:invalid擬似クラスを使う方法でもよさそうですね。
(jQueryの独自機能では無いですし、この手の事で単純な事は大抵CSSだけで出来ますが)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input:invalid').css('background-color', 'orange');
  $('input:valid').css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" required="required"/>
<button>Run</button>
```

Comment: mjyさん。なるほど、疑似クラスというのがあったのですね。参考になりました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

input等の要素が入力済みであるか、あるいはvalueプロパティを検査できるようなセレクタはjQueryにもないと思います。処理の部分をループの外に追い出したいということであれば [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) を使う手はありますが、判定の部分はやはり無名関数を使うことになります。

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.input')
    .css('background', '') //reset
    .filter(function(){ return $(this).val() !== ''; })
    .css('background', 'gray');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<input type="text" class="input">
<button>Check</button>
```

Comment: unarist♦さん。jQueryには無かったのですね。てっきり出来るものだと思っていました。ご回答ありがとうございます。